# User defined literal arguments are not constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, user-defined-literals

I'm testing out user defined literals. I want to make `_fac` return the factorial of the number.

Having it call a `constexpr` function works, however it doesn't let me do it with templates as the compiler complains that the arguments are not and cannot be `constexpr`.

I'm confused by this - aren't literals constant expressions? The `5` in `5_fac` is always a literal that can be evaluated during compile time, so why can't I use it as such?

First method:

```
constexpr int factorial_function(int x) {
  return (x > 0) ? x * factorial_function(x - 1) : 1;
}

constexpr int operator "" _fac(unsigned long long x) {
  return factorial_function(x); // this works
}
```

Second method:

```
template <int N> struct factorial_template {
  static const unsigned int value = N * factorial_template<N - 1>::value;
};
template <> struct factorial_template<0> {
  static const unsigned int value = 1;
};

constexpr int operator "" _fac(unsigned long long x) {
  return factorial_template<x>::value; // doesn't work - x is not a constexpr
}
```

Comment: I don't think any compiler implements those user-defined literals yet. How are you testing this?

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that was supported yet. I have one of those installed on a machine somewhere, now I'm tempted to work out those variadic templates :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
template <typename t>
constexpr t pow(t base, int exp) {
  return (exp > 0) ? base * pow(base, exp-1) : 1;
};

template <char...> struct literal;
template <> struct literal<> {
  static const unsigned int to_int = 0;
};
template <char c, char ...cv> struct literal<c, cv...> {
  static const unsigned int to_int = (c - '0') * pow(10, sizeof...(cv)) + literal<cv...>::to_int;
};

template <int N> struct factorial {
  static const unsigned int value = N * factorial<N - 1>::value;
};
template <> struct factorial<0> {
  static const unsigned int value = 1;
};

template <char ...cv>
constexpr unsigned int operator "" _fac()
{
  return factorial<literal<cv...>::to_int>::value;
}
```

**Huge thanks to KerrekSB!**

Comment: Downvoting, because the answer doesn't really answer the OPs stated questions, but only contains code.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if there's a better way in C++11 to do this than the current accepted answer, but with relaxed `constexpr` in C++14, you can just write "normal" code:

```
constexpr unsigned long long int operator "" _fac(unsigned long long int x) {
    unsigned long long int result = 1;
    for (; x >= 2; --x) {
        result *= x;
    }
    return result;
}

static_assert(5_fac == 120, "!");
```

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong, but I think constexpr functions can also be called with non-constant arguments (in which case they don't give a constant expression and are evaluated at runtime). Which wouldn't work well with non-type template arguments.

Comment: Well, presumably, the compiler would complain if you passed a non-compile-time-constant to the function then.  Could this be a way to solve the problem where template-ness trickles all the way up layers of code?

Comment: @MichaelPrice: Of course it could complain about passing non-const expressions to constexpr functions (and as I said, I'm not sure that I'm right). But that would mean that you'd generally need two functions which are exactly the same except for the `constexpr` keyword, one for constant expressions and one for all other expressions.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make use of constexpr with user defined literals, you apparently have to use a variadic template.  Take a look at the second listing in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#User-defined_literals) for an example.

Comment: You don't always have to use variadic templates to use `constexpr`, but this case does require it (but I know what you mean).

Comment: How can I turn a variadic template of `char` into `int`?

Comment: @Pubby - subtract 0x30 from it?  I'm not sure of a better way, but you might be able to use partial template specialization for it... though the thought hurts my head.

Comment: Why not include an example, instead of referring to Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

@Pubby. The easy way to digest the char non-type parameter pack is to cature it into an initializer list for a string.  Then you can use atoi, atof, etc:

```
#include <iostream>

template<char... Chars>
  int
  operator "" _suffix()
  {
    const char str[]{Chars..., '\0'};
    return atoi(str);
  }

int
main()
{
  std::cout << 12345_suffix << std::endl;
}
```

Remember to tack on a null character for the C-style functions.

Comment: The problem with that is it isn't `constexpr`. It's actually worse than passing `unsigned long long` as the argument type.